# A possible typo in Problem I.12.10 about Newton polynomial from textbook Analysis I by Amann/Escher

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I'm proving a remark in problem *I.12.10* from textbook *Analysis I* by Amann/Escher.

> [image]

The remark is as follows:

> $$(x_{n}-x_{0}) a_{n}+a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}=0$$

Here are relevant definitions from my textbook:

> [image]

Remark 12.10(b)

> [image]
>   [image]

---

**My issue:**

1. The authors define $f\left[x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n}\right]$ by $$f\left[x_{0}, \ldots, x_{n}\right] := \sum_{j=0}^{n} \frac{f\left(x_{j}\right)}{\prod_{k=0 \atop k \neq j}^{n}\left(x_{j}-x_{k}\right)}$$

I guess $$f\left[x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right] = f\left[x_{n}, \ldots, x_{1}\right] = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{f\left(x_{j}\right)}{\prod_{k=1 \atop k \neq j}^{n}\left(x_{j}-x_{k}\right)}$$

I'm not sure whether my guess is correct or not.

2. The authors said that $a_{n}=b_{n}$ for $1 \leq n \leq m$. Then $(x_{n}-x_{0}) a_{n}+a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}=0$ becomes $(x_{n}-x_{0}) a_{n}=0$, which is trivially wrong.

Could you please elaborate more on these points?

Comment: 1. Your guess is correct. You're just plugging $n-1$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ for $n$ and $x_0, \ldots, x_n$ into the definition of $f\left[x_0,\ldots,x_n\right]$.

Comment: Hi @darijgrinberg, I do not understand "plugging $n-1$". In the formula, I do not see $n-1$ eslewhere. Please address my concern 2 too. I'm extremely happy to receive your response ;)

Comment: You're plugging the $n-1$ in for $n$, not the other way round. For example, if you plug $2$ and $a,b,c$ for $n$ and $x_0, \ldots, x_n$, then you get $f\left[a,b,c\right] = \dfrac{f\left(a\right)}{\left(a-b\right)\left(a-c\right)} + \dfrac{f\left(b\right)}{\left(b-a\right)\left(b-c\right)} + \dfrac{f\left(c\right)}{\left(c-a\right)\left(c-b\right)}$.

Comment: I don't understand the Hint to part (c) either. But you can prove it quite easily just using the definition of $f\left[x_0,\ldots,x_n\right]$ (and the identity $\dfrac{1}{x_j-x_0} - \dfrac{1}{x_j-x_n} = \dfrac{x_0-x_n}{\left(x_j-x_0\right)\left(x_j-x_n\right)}$).

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated support @darijgrinberg ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer I sketched in the comments, in more detail.

**Background.**

Let $\mathbb{N}=\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.

Fix a field $\mathbb{K}$. Let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. (In your
setting, $V=\mathbb{K}$, but there is nothing gained from this
specialization.) If $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ is nonzero and if $v\in V$, then
$\dfrac{v}{\lambda}$ shall denote the vector $\lambda^{-1}v\in V$.

Fix a map $f:\mathbb{K}\rightarrow V$.

If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and if $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ are any $n+1$ distinct
elements of $\mathbb{K}$, then we define a vector $f\left[  x_{0},x_{1}
,\ldots,x_{n}\right]  \in V$ by setting
\begin{equation}
f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\label{darij1.eq.def-fbra}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Everything I am doing can be generalized even further by letting $\mathbb{K}$
be any commutative ring (instead of a field). In this case, instead of
requiring $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ to be distinct, we need to require that
their pairwise differences $x_{i}-x_{j}$ for $i\neq j$ are invertible in
$\mathbb{K}$. Other than that, the arguments work the same. But I will keep to
the case when $\mathbb{K}$ is a field, just to keep my statements shorter.

Let me restate \eqref{darij1.eq.def-fbra} as follows: If $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and
if $a_{0},a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}$ are any $n+1$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{K}$,
then
\begin{equation}
f\left[  a_{0},a_{1},\ldots,a_{n}\right]  =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{f\left(
a_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  a_{j}-a_{k}\right)  }.
\label{darij1.eq.def-fbra-a}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Indeed, this follows by applying \eqref{darij1.eq.def-fbra} to $x_{i}=a_{i}$.

**Your first question** is asking why every positive integer $n$ and
every $n$ distinct elements $x_{1}
,x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ of $\mathbb{K}$ satisfy
\begin{equation}
f\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\label{darij1.eq.2}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

*Proof of \eqref{darij1.eq.2}:* Let $n$ be a positive integer, and let $x_{1}
,x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}$ be $n$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{K}$. Then,
\eqref{darij1.eq.def-fbra-a} (applied to $n-1$ and $x_{i+1}$ instead of $n$
and $a_{i}$) yields
\begin{align*}
f\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]    & =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j+1}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j+1}-x_{k+1}\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j+1}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ;\\k+1\neq j+1}}\left(
x_{j+1}-x_{k+1}\right)  }\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{since the statement "}k\neq
j\text{" is equivalent to "}k+1\neq
j+1\text{"}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j+1}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j+1}}\left(
x_{j+1}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have substituted }k\text{ for }k+1\text{ in the
product}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have substituted }j\text{ for }j+1\text{ in the
sum}\right)  .
\end{align*}
This proves \eqref{darij1.eq.2}. $\blacksquare$

**Your second question** is about proving the following claim:

> **Proposition 1.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $x_{0},x_{1}
> ,\ldots,x_{n}$ be any $n+1$ distinct elements of $\mathbb{K}$. Then,
> \begin{equation}
> f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  =\dfrac{f\left[  x_{0},x_{1}
> ,\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  -f\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  }
> {x_{0}-x_{n}}.
> \end{equation}

I don't understand the hint that Amann and Escher give for this proposition,
but fortunately you can just as well prove it by straightforward manipulation
of sums:

*Proof of Proposition 1.* We have $0\neq n$ (since $n$ is positive) and thus
$x_{0}\neq x_{n}$ (since $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ are distinct). Thus,
$x_{0}-x_{n}\neq0$.

Applying
\eqref{darij1.eq.def-fbra} to $n-1$ instead of $n$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\label{darij1.pf.prop1.1}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Now, fix $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $. Then, $j\neq n$, so that
$x_{j}\neq x_{n}$ (since $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ are distinct), and thus
$x_{j}-x_{n}\neq0$. Hence, we can divide by $x_{j}-x_{n}$. Moreover, $n$ is a
$k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  $ satisfying $k\neq j$ (since $n\neq j$);
therefore, the product $\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots
,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  $ contains a factor for
$k=n$. Splitting off this factor, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  =\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  .
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }
{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }  & =\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)
}\nonumber\\
& =\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{
0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }
.
\label{darij1.pf.prop1.2}
\tag{5}
\end{align}

Forget that we fixed $j$. We thus have proven
\eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.2} for each $j\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  $.
Now,
\eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.1} becomes
\begin{align*}
f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]    & =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}
\underbrace{\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }
}_{\substack{=\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)
}{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq
j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.2})}}}\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\end{align*}
Comparing this with
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)
}{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq
j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }+\underbrace{\left(  x_{n}
-x_{n}\right)  }_{=0}\cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{n}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq n}}\left(
x_{n}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have split off the addend for }j=n\text{ from
the sum}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  },
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}
-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\label{darij1.pf.prop1.x0xn-1}
\tag{6}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, fix $j\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. Then, $j\neq0$,
so that $x_{j}\neq x_{0}$ (since $x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ are distinct), and
thus $x_{j}-x_{0}\neq0$. Hence, we can divide by $x_{j}-x_{0}$. Moreover, $0$
is a $k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  $ satisfying $k\neq j$ (since $0\neq
j$); therefore, the product $\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{
0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  $ contains a
factor for $k=0$. Splitting off this factor, we obtain
\begin{equation}
\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  =\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  .
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }
{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }  & =\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)
}\nonumber\\
& =\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{
1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }
.
\label{darij1.pf.prop1.5}
\tag{7}
\end{align}

Forget that we fixed $j$. We thus have proven \eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.5} for
each $j\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  $. Now, \eqref{darij1.eq.2} becomes
\begin{align}
f\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]    & =\sum_{j=1}^{n}
\underbrace{\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in
\left\{  1,2,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }
}_{\substack{=\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)
}{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq
j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\\text{(by \eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.5})}}}\\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\end{align}
Comparing this with
\begin{align*}
& \sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)
}{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq
j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }+\underbrace{\left(  x_{0}
-x_{0}\right)  }_{=0}\cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{0}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq0}}\left(
x_{0}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& \qquad\left(  \text{here, we have split off the addend for }j=0\text{ from
the sum}\right)  \\
& =\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  },
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
f\left[  x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}
-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }.
\end{equation}
Subtracting this equality from \eqref{darij1.pf.prop1.x0xn-1}, we obtain
\begin{align*}
& f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  -f\left[  x_{1},x_{2}
,\ldots,x_{n}\right]  \\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }-\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{j}
-x_{0}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(  x_{j}\right)  }{\prod
\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}  ;\\k\neq j}}\left(
x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\underbrace{\left(  \left(  x_{j}-x_{n}\right)  -\left(
x_{j}-x_{0}\right)  \right)  }_{=x_{0}-x_{n}}\cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& =\sum_{j=0}^{n}\left(  x_{0}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }\\
& =\left(  x_{0}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot\underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{n}\dfrac{f\left(
x_{j}\right)  }{\prod\limits_{\substack{k\in\left\{  0,1,\ldots,n\right\}
;\\k\neq j}}\left(  x_{j}-x_{k}\right)  }}_{\substack{=f\left[  x_{0}
,x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  \\\text{(by
\eqref{darij1.eq.def-fbra})}}}\\
& =\left(  x_{0}-x_{n}\right)  \cdot f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right]
.
\end{align*}
We can divide both sides of this equality by $x_{0}-x_{n}$ (since $x_{0}
-x_{n}\neq0$), and thus obtain
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots,x_{n-1}\right]  -f\left[  x_{1}
,x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right]  }{x_{0}-x_{n}}=f\left[  x_{0},x_{1},\ldots
,x_{n}\right]  .
\end{equation}
This proves Proposition 1. $\blacksquare$

Comment: To be honest, I haven’t read your answer – and this might go against what’s reasonable – but I upvoted anyway just for your effort. Chapeau!

Comment: @k.stm: Thank you! The main purpose of my answer is for me to double-check my proof; I'm pretty sure you can easily reconstruct the computation from my hint in the comments. (The effort has been less than it might seem, as I've been extensively using Scientific WorkPlace in writing the formulas, and as one half of the proof is essentially a copypaste of another. I think it took me half an hour in total.)

Comment: I greatly appreciate your time typing this answer. Thank you so much ;)

Comment: Honestly, I think that you should try Tex editor [BakomaTex](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/about.php). It has a unique WYSIWYG feature. You will save a huge amount of time by directly editing the instant LIVE preview (not just source file) ;)